Improving the waveshape and amplitude of a saw-tooth generator
I am a student in in college level physics and so I do not have a lot of knowledge when it comes to circuits and the different electrical components. Still, as a project, I decided to try to build an analog synthesizer and so here is the circuit I have designed, but not yet built.
The problem I am currently facing is that the simulation does not show the voltage across the speaker that I expected; the amplitude is too low (sound not loud enough), and the waveshape is not what I expected (appears to be an exponential curve rather than a saw-tooth).

Here is what I did to solve the problem:
I tried to increase the output voltage by lowering the resistances in the "tension divider" (1kΩ / 1kΩ).  But this caused the output waveshape to look like an exponential discharge instead of a linear discharge (sawtooth wave).  This is probably due to the R-C time constant becoming too small (the R-C is formed by the "tension divider" & the dc-blocking capacitor).  This is not the waveform that I want.
Then I tried to keep the waveshape to what I wanted (sawtooth).  I tweaked the resistance values in the "tension divider" until the wave form was OK (just about to change from linear to exponential), but the maximum output voltage across the speaker is very low, just 51mV.  This amplitude is very small and so the speaker volume will be very low.
So my question is: are there some small adjustments /modifications/ additions I could make to my circuit to fulfill these 2 conditions and generate an audible saw tooth waveform through the speaker?

Feed the speaker directly from the capacitor. Increase the capacitor value until the time constant is large enough. It will need >1000uF for low frequencies.

Your question is unclear. Which part of the circuit do you want to reduce the input impedance of? Do you mean you want to decrease the output impedance of your circuit? Because that would actually help. Why is the voltage divider needed? (N.B.: "tension" has not been used as synonym for potential difference in English for 100 years or so except in a few archaic set phrases)

thank you for this quick answer. I realized I indeed mentioned impedance in the title without really understanding what I even meant by that. As for the tension divider, sorry, English isn't my first language I just assumed that it translated directly from French to English.
I will try your capacitor suggestion thank you.
→ It ended up modifying the wave form and saturating the signal, and I put a 10F capacitor, which is way more than what I will have access to when I will come around to built the synth.

@ThePhoton  I  have (hopefully) improved both the heading, and the body, of this question.

Suggestions:

Remove the "tension divider".  Continue without this.  If this is needed, then this can be moved to the input of the op-amp (I can provide more advice on this if required - I suspect this won't be required).
Put a voltage buffer stage (also called "common-collector" amplifier) after the op-amp output and before the dc-blocking capacitor (100uF).  This should be designed to deliver much more current than what the op-amp is capable of.  For advice on this, please refer to the post at the link below, but remember that you will need to change the values to suit your particular application.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/688522/341959
Increase the dc-blocking capacitor.  You can do this by putting 2 or more 100uF capacitors in parallel.  Be careful what type of capacitor you use, electrolytic types are usually polarised, meaning they cannot tolerate negative voltage.  Alternatively, consider removing this capacitor, and removing the DC component of the output voltage by alternative means (these are discussed further below).
If you need even more current than what the common collector amplifier can deliver, then you can use a push-pull type voltage buffer stage instead.  For advice on this, please refer to the post at the link below:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/689296/341959

Suggestions for removing the big 100uF capacitor:
This capacitor causes a problem: to achieve a sufficiently long time constant with a load of such low resistance (8Ω speaker) it needs to have a large value of capacitance.  For this application, it also should be non-polarised, since the voltage across it will be both positive and negative.  However, there is a problem: capacitors that are non-polarised and have large values of capacitance are expensive and hard to get.
We can remove this capacitor by replacing it with a short.  However, we still need to remove the DC component of the voltage being applied to the load.  We can do this in several ways:

By placing a DC blocking capacitor between the output of the saw-tooth generator (the voltage on the 2.2uF capacitor) and the input of the op-amp.
By placing a DC blocking capacitor between the output of the op-amp, and the input of the new buffer stage suggested above to increase output current.
By re-designing the saw-tooth generator to automatically have an output with no dc-component.  I will leave the details of this for you to discover once you have had more experience with electronics.

Of course, for each of these options, your circuit must have two power supplies: a positive, and a negative; this is necessary to generate the negative part of the output voltage.  You have shown this to be the case in your schematic, so that is good.
Note that it is possible to achieve what you want with just one power supply, and by using standard polarised electrolytic capacitors (which are quite easy to get and low-cost), but I will leave that for another discussion.
General-Purpose Audio Amplifier
You may like to consider designing and building a general-purpose amplifier suitable for driving an 8Ω speaker to between 0.25W to 1W of power, which is more than enough power for hobby applications.  Such an amplifier would be very suitable for this question; simply connect the output of your saw-tooth generator to the input of the amplifier, and connect the 8Ω speaker to the output of the amplifier, and you will very clearly hear the sound generated by the saw-tooth waveform generator.  There are many internet resources you could refer to design and build such an amplifier, one such link is below; this particular post discusses two different designs, one that requires a dc-blocking capacitor, and one that does not.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/688822/341959

The op-amp is already in a voltage buffer configuration. What would adding a second unity buffer stage do to improve the circuit?

@ThePhoton  It is not the voltage gain that is the issue it is the load current.  The load current of an 8-ohm speaker is usually too much for an op-amp and risks damaging the op-amp, particularly those types that do not have output current limiting (check the op-amp datasheet).  An output stage made of discrete transistors will deliver more current to the load than an op-amp -without risking damaging the op-amp.

Without knowing which op-amp is being used I don't think we know whether that's true or not. (But it would be correct to point out that a high current op-amp would be needed for this application) At the very least it's worth clarifying that you mean a discrete transistor stage rather than an op-amp stage.

@ThePhoton The OPs own admission: " I do not have a lot of knowledge when it comes to circuits and the different electrical components".   I think it would be quite safe to suspect the OP does not know the difference between a normal op-amp, and one capable of safely delivering high current to an 8-phm load.

Fair, and they also might not know how to construct an appropriate buffer from discrete transistors. Or to add a transistor buffer inside the loop of the existing op-amp buffer stage.

@ThePhoton  (A) The link shows how to construct a buffer using common parts.  (B) The buffer can be either within the loop, or outside the loop - since this not a hi-fi system, then it won't make any difference in this application.  We can cross that bridge if we need to later (one step at a time).  Cheers.

hello the chip i planned on using was the TL074CN. I hope this provides some help. I also can tell you that the speaker I intended on using has a rating of 60W (see https://www.pasco.com/products/lab-apparatus/waves-and-sound/resonance-and-sound/wa-9900#specs-panel).
As a side note, I would tell you that while I am ready to go for the best solution there is to my problem (as I am sure there exists many), I would also like to understand what I am doing rather than simply making it work through "electrical magic". Hence, the simpler the solution (in terms of electrical principles), the better

That being said, I am very grateful for the help you are delivering so far and I will look into the solution you suggested.

The TL074CN does have short-circuit protection at its output pin, but will only deliver at most ~25mA out of that pin.  Even if all of that 25mA reaches the speaker, that will only create ~5mW of power (simple formula P=I^2 R).   You could try not using a current buffer and seeing what sound loudness you get - you should hear something, the datasheet of the speaker states sensitivity is 85dB (this is for 1W of power), so 5mW will be about 200 times less than this, so about 60 to 65dB.


the waveshape is not what I expected (appears to be an exponential curve rather than a saw-tooth).

If a fixed voltage is applied to an RC circuit, the capacitor will charge or discharge with an exponentially decaying waveform. To make the voltage across a capacitor vary linearly with time, the capacitor needs to be charged or discharged with constant current.
Your circuit feeds a rectangular voltage wave into an RC circuit, and thus produces pulses with exponential rise and fall. To avoid this, what is usually done is to place the capacitor inside the op-amp feedback loop, like so.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The ratio between R4 and R5 determines the ratio between the rate of rise of the rising edge, and the rate of fall of the falling edge.

If one wishes to have "minimal" rise (or fall) time, one can place a diode in parallel with R2, and eliminate R4 and R5 like so:

simulate this circuit
R6 was added to reduce spikes that appeared in the simulation. They may, or may not, appear in an actual circuit, so R6 may or may not be necessary. It was chosen to be much less than R2. Here is a simulation:

As has been mentioned in both the comments and another answer, a standard op-amp does not have the drive capability for a low impedance load, such as an 8 \$\Omega\$ speaker. You need a buffer or power amplifier for that. I make no suggestion regarding the best choice for such a buffer or power amplifier.
